# Unable to resolve dependency 'openssl.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.x64 (= 1.0.2.1)'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, curl

I get this error repeatedly when trying to install third party package in vs package manager,

> Unable to resolve dependency 'openssl.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.x64 (= 1.0.2.1)'.

when I am trying to install curl or libssh2 in visual studio 2013. Why is that ? 
I tried to install openssl.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.x64 (= 1.0.2.1) but it did not work for me ? What am I doing wrong ?

[image: Here is the error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the exact same issue...
The only way for me to "fix" it was to install the version that it wanted, in your and my case was v.1.0.2

PM> Install-Package openssl -Version 1.0.2

Even after doing that, when you try to perhaps let it update the version on its own (whether by command line or package manager), the same problem error message comes out.

Hope it helps at least a litte bit.

Comment: It doesn't help because I try to install curl package which has openssl as dependency. Is there a way to ignore dependencies in NuGet?

P.S.
Microsoft, I hate you!